# Where I can get information about internal working of clipboard?

Tags: c#, string, winapi, clipboard

I would like to read some articles or books about how works windows clipboard inside, but I can't find at least one article that was deeper than standard API references or examples of using .

I'm working with windows clipboard over standart winapi and I obtain some strange results.

Case 1: I write to clipboard some unicode string and remember address of that string. Then I close clipboard, and repeat following procedure:
open clipboard, get address of my unicode string, close clipboard.

I think that I must receive same addresses of clipboard content but it isn't. Why?

```
        //1.) Copying string to clipboard
        if (WinAPI.OpenClipboard(owner))
        {
            WinAPI.EmptyClipboard();

            IntPtr exampleStringPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("Example");

            Console.WriteLine("setting address: {0}", exampleStringPtr.ToInt32());

            WinAPI.SetClipboardData(WinAPI.CF_UNICODETEXT, exampleStringPtr);

            WinAPI.CloseClipboard();
        }

        //2.) Getting string from clipboard
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
            if (WinAPI.OpenClipboard(owner))
            {
                IntPtr exampleStringPtr = WinAPI.GetClipboardData(WinAPI.CF_UNICODETEXT);

                Console.WriteLine("getting address: {0}", exampleStringPtr.ToInt32());

                WinAPI.GlobalLock(exampleStringPtr);

                var s = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(exampleStringPtr);

                WinAPI.GlobalUnlock(exampleStringPtr);
                WinAPI.CloseClipboard();
            }
```

case 2: I write to clipboard some string, close clipboard, change string (in unmanaged memory) and again open clipboard and read this string. To my surprise, I obtain SAME string address and my UNCHANGED string.

```
        //1.) Copying string to clipboard
        if (WinAPI.OpenClipboard(owner))
        {
            WinAPI.EmptyClipboard();

            IntPtr exampleStringPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("Loooooooooooonng String Example");

            Console.WriteLine("setting address: {0}", exampleStringPtr.ToInt32());

            WinAPI.SetClipboardData(WinAPI.CF_UNICODETEXT, exampleStringPtr);

            WinAPI.CloseClipboard();

            //2.) Change string - replace first 10 characters on one any symbol 
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Marshal.WriteByte(exampleStringPtr + i, 50);
            }

            //3.) Obtain string and make sure that string was changed
            Console.WriteLine("changed string: {0}", Marshal.PtrToStringUni(exampleStringPtr));
        }


            //2.) Getting string from clipboard
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                if (WinAPI.OpenClipboard(owner))
                {
                    IntPtr exampleStringPtr = WinAPI.GetClipboardData(WinAPI.CF_UNICODETEXT);

                    Console.WriteLine("getting address: {0}", exampleStringPtr.ToInt32());

                    WinAPI.GlobalLock(exampleStringPtr);

                    var s = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(exampleStringPtr);

                    Console.WriteLine("obtained string: {0}", s);

                    WinAPI.CloseClipboard();
                }
```

Now I'm thinking that clipboard copy all memory block in SetClipboardData to other memory and source block can be copied several times. I can't understand, why I can't   free my unmanaged memory for string immediately after SetClipboardData execution?

I have many questions and I think that some literature will make it clear

UPDATE:

to  Raymond Chen, Jonathan Potter, Eric Brown: thank's for your answers, but I edited my second test that it would be more correct and now it shows following:
 I change source string BEFORE clipboard was closed and I may think it is valid operation and it removes answers  that I make it after clipboard was closed. Then I get this string and results shows that is changed, then I get this string by invoking GetClipboardData and results shows that string was changed and pointer is same. Then I close clipboard open it again and read string again. What I obtain now? string address is same as address of source string but string is UNCHANGED. Here's this code:

```
        //1.) Copying string to clipboard
        if (WinAPI.OpenClipboard(owner))
        {
            WinAPI.EmptyClipboard();

            IntPtr exampleStringPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("Loooooooooooonng String Example");

            Console.WriteLine("setting address: {0}", exampleStringPtr.ToInt32());

            WinAPI.SetClipboardData(WinAPI.CF_UNICODETEXT, exampleStringPtr);

            //2.) Change string while clipboard isn't closed - replace first 10 characters on one any symbol 
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Marshal.WriteByte(exampleStringPtr + i, 50);
            }

            //3.) Obtain string and make sure that string was changed
            Console.WriteLine("changed string: {0}", Marshal.PtrToStringUni(exampleStringPtr));

            //4.) Get this string from clipboard and make sure that clipboard was changed
            exampleStringPtr = WinAPI.GetClipboardData(WinAPI.CF_UNICODETEXT);

            Console.WriteLine("getting address of changed string: {0}", exampleStringPtr.ToInt32());

            var lockedPtr = WinAPI.GlobalLock(exampleStringPtr);

            var s = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(exampleStringPtr);
            WinAPI.GlobalUnlock(lockedPtr);

            Console.WriteLine("obtained string: {0}", s);

            WinAPI.CloseClipboard();

        }
            Console.WriteLine("\n-------Close and open clipboard------------------\n");

            //5.) Getting string from clipboard
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                if (WinAPI.OpenClipboard(owner))
                {
                    IntPtr exampleStringPtr = WinAPI.GetClipboardData(WinAPI.CF_UNICODETEXT);

                    Console.WriteLine("getting address: {0}", exampleStringPtr.ToInt32());

                    var lockedPtr = WinAPI.GlobalLock(exampleStringPtr);

                    var s = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(lockedPtr);

                    WinAPI.GlobalUnlock(lockedPtr);

                    Console.WriteLine("obtained string: {0}", s);

                    WinAPI.CloseClipboard();
                }
```

I run program, paused it and analyzied memory by WinDbg. Then I make screenshot of results and provide for it you. http://postimg.org/image/are6um7yv/ So, my tests and screenshot shows that:

1.) We have several copies of one source object in memory
2.) If I change source memory given to SetClipboardData invoke before closing clipboard, after opening it again clipboard restore source object even on source address.

Isn't is? Can anyone explain, whether these clauses are true or not?

UPDATE 2: Ok.. I was rewriting my third test on C++. it's here:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "conio.h"

int main()
{
HWND owner = GetConsoleWindow();

//1.) Copying string to clipboard
if (OpenClipboard(owner))
{
    EmptyClipboard();

    //WCHAR *str = L"Loooong string example";
    char *str = "Loooooooong string Example";

    int cch = strlen(str);

    char* strptr = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, (cch + 1));

    printf("setting (segment??) address: %X \n", strptr);

    LPVOID lockedPtr = GlobalLock(strptr);
    printf("locked setting address: %X \n", lockedPtr);

    // copy
    memcpy(lockedPtr, str, cch);

    GlobalUnlock(strptr);

    // set to clipboard
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, strptr);

    //2.) Change string while clipboard isn't closed - replace first 10 characters on one any symbol 
    lockedPtr = GlobalLock(strptr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ((char*)lockedPtr)[i] = 50;
    }
    GlobalUnlock(strptr);

    //3.) Obtain string and make sure that string was changed
    lockedPtr = GlobalLock(strptr);
    printf("changed string: %s \n", lockedPtr);
    GlobalUnlock(strptr);

    //4.) Get this string from clipboard and make sure that clipboard was changed
    strptr = (char*)GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

    printf("getting address: %X \n", strptr);

    lockedPtr = GlobalLock(strptr);

    printf("locked getting address: %X \n", lockedPtr);

    printf("obtained string: %s \n", (char*)lockedPtr );

    GlobalUnlock(strptr);

    CloseClipboard();

}

printf("\n-------Close and open clipboard------------------\n");

//5.) Getting string from clipboard
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //Sleep(1000);
    if (OpenClipboard(owner))
    {
        HANDLE exampleStringPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

        printf("getting address: %X \n", exampleStringPtr);

        char* lockedPtr = (char*)GlobalLock(exampleStringPtr);

        printf("locked getting address: %X \n", lockedPtr);
        printf("obtained string: %s \n", lockedPtr);

        GlobalUnlock(exampleStringPtr);

        CloseClipboard();
    }
}

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Really, now when I invoke GetClipboardData then I obtain the same pointer to the data all the time. But sometimes it was different from locked pointer of first string that I putted to the clipboard.

But although I'm writing this test on C++, I still have same effect I was writeing early.

If I change source memory block after invoking SetClipboardData and then try to invoke GetClipboardData, I obtain my changed memory block. But when I close this clipboard and then open it again, my changed memory block was overriten with some info, I don't know, and when I invoke GetClipboardData, that memory block was restored to initial state as if I didn't change it.

From where clipboard "knows" how to restore this block if it hasn't its copies and I changed source block?

I recorded little screencast that shows in what moment memory restored http://screencast.com/t/5t3wc9LS

Comment: The pointer returned by `GlobalLock` is valid only until you call `GlobalUnlock`. There is no requirement that locking something twice will give you the same pointer each time, nor is there a requirement that calling `GetClipboardData` twice will give you the same handle each time. In the second program, you are writing to memory you no longer own, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Raymond, thanks for comment but I retrieve different pointers after invoking GetClipboardData before locking and unlocking.

Regarding on second test, I updated my test and now I change memory before clipboard was closed and I obtained same results as I had obtained in my second test.

Comment: There are three errors in this code. First, `StringToHGlobalUni` allocates memory via `LocalAlloc`, not `GlobalAlloc`, and the clipboard requires `GlobalAlloc`. (`StringToHGlobalUni` is misleadingly named.) Second, the code modifies memory after calling `SetClipboardData`. Third, you modify the memory via the handle rather than the locked pointer. If you are coding in C#, you should use the existing `Clipboard` class. If you are trying to learn to use the low-level clipboard APIs, then you should be coding in C or C++ which make it easier to meet requirements of the low-level APIs.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I undestood that tests in .net environment may show false results becauseof there is different hidden manipulatings with managed and unmanaged memory (probably). I rewriting code in C++ and I see that when I get clipboard contents I really obtain same pointers all the time. But clipboard is still restored after my changing of source memory block, what's happened? P.S. I lock memory before changing now

Comment: As already mentioned several times *you are not allowed to modify the memory after calling `SetClipboardData`*.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [`SetClipboardData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say quite clearly that it does **not** copy the data you provide - instead, the clipboard owns the data handle and although you can still read from it until the clipboard is closed, you must not write to or free the data once the `SetClipboardData()` call has succeeded.

Once you've closed the clipboard you no longer own the clipboard and the data object is not safe to use at all, even for reading, as another process may have changed the clipboard contents. Your tests at modifying the data after closing the clipboard worked by luck, not because they are supposed to.

> If SetClipboardData succeeds, the system owns the object identified by
>   the hMem parameter. The application may not write to or free the data
>   once ownership has been transferred to the system, but it can lock and
>   read from the data until the CloseClipboard function is called. (The
>   memory must be unlocked before the Clipboard is closed.)

Edit: Because you seem to have trouble with the concept of resource ownership and undefined behaviour, maybe this analogy will help.

```
// allocate 1 byte of memory
char* ptr = malloc(sizeof(char));
// set the byte to the letter A
*ptr = 'A'; 
// free the memory
free(ptr);
// set the byte to B
*ptr = 'B';
// verify that the byte is set to B
printf("byte contains %c\n", *ptr);
// allocate another byte of memory
char* ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(char));
// are they the same byte? maybe
printf("byte contains %c - first was %lx, second is %lx\n", *ptr2, ptr, ptr2);
```

I hope you will see that this code is completely wrong. We allocate memory, write to it, **free it**, and then after that, we write to it and read from it again. And yet if you compile and run this code, there's a good chance it will work. There's also a good chance that the second allocation will return the same address as the first allocation. What's going on?

This is called **undefined behaviour**. The language doesn't define what happens in a situation like this. When you free memory, you no longer own it, and you must not write to it nor read from it. If it works, or appears to work, it's a coincidence, nothing more. There is no guarantee it will always work. There is no point continually performing tests to try to prove that somehow it does work - nothing alters the fact that the behaviour is undefined. It might work, it might not. Don't do it.

Comment: I update my post and screenshot shows that we have several data objects in memory simultaniously, isn't it?

Comment: It's all undefined behaviour. Once you have called `SetClipboardData()` you no longer own the data and must not change it.

Comment: What exactly means "you no longer own the data"? I rewrite code in C++ so it don't include any hiding transformations with data and I can change memory block after calling SetClipboardData and second calling of it shows that clipboard gets changed data. But clipboard is opened again, that memory was rewriting on original. How to explain this fact?

Comment: "you no longer own the data" is a rule.  Read the rules, follow the rules, or you're going to have trouble.  Do not try to make up new rules, even if they appear to work in specific situations.  There are many ways that incorrect clipboard implementations can interfere with, or cause unintended/unwanted actions within other programs.

Answer (score -1):

`SetClipboardData` copies the data in the given global handle.  Once the clipboard is closed, the global handle should be freed (and not before).  `GetClipboardData` returns the (internal) memory handle; you should treat this handle as a read-only buffer.

Comment: `SetClipboardData()` does not copy the data.